# Align ggplot2 points without having them overlap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Is there any possible way to make the points on a boxplot show and not have them overlap each other if they arent unique?

Currently:

[image]

I want it to look like this (with the colours and other features):

[image]

I tried beeswarm and I'm getting the error:
`Warning in f(...) : The default behavior of beeswarm has changed in version 0.6.0. In versions <0.6.0, this plot would have been dodged on the y-axis.  In versions >=0.6.0, grouponX=FALSE must be explicitly set to group on y-axis. Please set grouponX=TRUE/FALSE to avoid this warning and ensure proper axis choice.`

even though I have `geom_beeswarm(grouponY=TRUE)`

Comment: There is no `grouponY` argument to `ggbeeswarm::geom_beeswarm()`. There is `groupOnX` as the warning message tells you, but I think the warning has a typo and it is spelled with capital `O`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this ...

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(x = "label", y = rnorm(100, 10, 10)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Slight modifications to Carl's answer could be to:

- Move the geom_jitter layer below the geom_boxplot layer, so that the points show through the box; or
- Make the box more transparent to allow the points to be visible

```
tibble(x = "label", y = rnorm(100, 10, 10)) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, alpha ) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1)
```

Alternatively, have you considered using a [violin plot](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_violin.html)? It can more effectively show the density of the distribution, as the width of the plot is proportional to the proportion of data points around that level (for the y axis).